# In extjs4 how to apply email validation to editable combobox

Tags: combobox, extjs4, email-validation

I am working in extjs4. I have following field=

```
{
   xtype : 'combo',
   queryMode : 'local',
   multiSelect : true,
   valueField : 'id',
   displayField : 'emailAddress',
   fieldLabel : 'Email address',
   editable : true
}
```

So i am allowing user to enter email address manually also.So user enters email and press enter key.I want apply validation on editing in such a way that when user manually enters email address, then after pressing enter key,combo should accept that email only if its valid email.So how to apply such validation in extjs4 to combo

Answer (score 0):

```
{
xtype : 'combo',
queryMode : 'local',
multiSelect : true,
valueField : 'id',
displayField : 'emailAddress',
fieldLabel : 'Email address',
editable : true,
**vtype:'email'**
}
```

Validations on the form fields are done using vTypes, it seems to be working fine on code editor. Test it out.

Comment: thanx for reply sir. I tried as u said. But its not working in above case